# Fix MS Access database to SQL Server over WiFi VPN - Update or CancelUpdate without AddNew or Edit

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, wifi, vpn

I currently have an MS Access DB connected to SQL Server 2012. From my office which has a strong network connection to the server I don't have any issues using the database. However, we have users whom are connected to the company VPN over a WiFi connection. The are receiving the following errors when navigating through a form ON THE SAME RECORD and sometimes when saving, but happening intermittently.

- Update or CancelUpdate without AddNew or Edit
- This record has been changed by another user since you started
  editing it. If you save the record you will overwrite the changes the
  other user made. Copying the changes to the clipboard will let you
  look at the values the other user entered, and then paste your
  changes back in if you decide to make changes.

I have checked all VBA code to make sure that I'm not incorrectly saving the form. I have also eliminated the issue with NULL bit fields between Access and SQL Server in addition to adding a Timestamp to every table.

I was thinking that this could be due to a slow connection latency issue. Does anyone have any ideas around this issue so that the database can be used without these errors.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no issues for users with a good connection and issues only for others using WiFi, it is most likely due to "holes" in the connection rather than pure latency. Of course, such breakes in connection can be regarded as extreme latency but generally not.

There really is no way around this other than establish better connection, not even error handling in Access as it is on the network level, and your application would be flooded with error handling code.

Comment: Hi Gustav, would using the same ODBC connection string with a single username and password for multiple users cause this problem? Would it be necessary to create a new login for each new user

Comment: Nothing related to this. As you describe it, it is solely a network issue.